# Is is possible to return from a method and have the thread still running for another process

Tags: java, microservices, return-value, java-threads

I'm looking to trigger two messages sent back to a micro service from the one call.
I want the response to be sent firstly (its an acceptance message) and then the contents from the sendPort2Response method to be sent, the current functionality sends the response last - is this even possible to do?

```
public Port2RequestResponse processPort2Request(Port2Request request) {
        FMNP getFMNPRequestObject = unmarshalInputRequest(request.getXmlPortMessage());
        Port2RequestResponse response = new Port2RequestResponse();

        response.setResult(getSuccessResponse(getFMNPRequestObject.getPort().getDonor()));

        Thread t = new Thread(){
            @SneakyThrows
            @Async
            public void run(){
                sendPort2Response(request);
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
        };
        t.start();
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: What is the protocol that you are using? If this is something like REST that should be "request-reply", then you cannot have multiple "replies" for a single "request". You could think about i.e. web-sockets, where you can send multiple messages in both directions between client and server.

Comment: It's soap so I assumed there wouldn't be a problem from a message perspective, it was more my understanding of how threads worked and is it possible to have a thread continue running while the method which holds the thread completes and returns if that makes sense

Comment: With SOAP (that uses HTTP as underlying protocol) it is not possible to send two messages (responses) from server on top of a single client request. The reason for that is the server closing of something like session/request context after first response. If you try to send the second one (after the closing) you will get the error like "ContextCloseException" (this is just sample, not sure about real exception name). You could try to return two responses, and you will see such an exception.